# Macro to Filter Pivot Table

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I have a dataset where i want to click on a cell in column A and it filters a pivot table on a different worksheet. I have this code so far:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then           
            Sheets("Labor Detail").Select
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("WBS1").ClearAllFilters
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("WBS1").CurrentPage = Range("A2").Value 
               End If
    End If
End Sub
```

It does what i want but only for one cell. I want to be able to click on ANY cell in column A and have the cell value filter the pivot table. How do i specify a range instead of just one cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Labor Detail").Select
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("WBS1").ClearAllFilters
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("WBS1").CurrentPage = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

I got rid of `Selection.Count = 1` as I don't think that's really doing anything. Instead I'm testing against `Target.Value` to make sure you have something to filter your pivot table by.

Comment: YOu should also try to not use Select.  Just access the pivot table directly like: Sheets("Labor Detail").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("WBS1").